# odata TreeTable with empty row because of slash?

Tags: odata, sapui5

I have a TreeTable which shows data from oData service. Some of the data fields contains symbols of slash ("/", f.e. cats/dogs). My service understands them like a new kind of parameter and doesn't display them in a TreeTable (gives a blank row).

Here is my code:

```
oData = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(".../categories/categories.xsodata/", false);
  oData.read("/Categories/",
  null,
  null,
  false,
  function(oData, oResponse){ 

            flat = {};
            for (var i = 0; i < oData.results.length; ++i) {
            var item, group, type, code;
            var getSubNode = function(obj, key) {
                     if (!obj[key]) {
                       obj[key] = {'NAME': key}
                     }                    

                     return obj[key];
                   };                  
                   item = oData.results[i];
                   group = getSubNode(flat, item.PET_GROUP);
                   type = getSubNode(group, item.PET_TYPE);


                   item.NAME = item.GENDER;
                   item.__metadata = "";
                   type[item.GENDER] = item;
                   }

            data = {flat : flat,};           
  });
   ojModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        ojModel.setData(data);


        oTable.setModel(ojModel); 
        oTable.bindRows("/flat");       

        return oTable;
```

Maybe there is a solution for this?

Comment: Workaround is to change that character in backend and replace again in the front end using formatter.. We also had this issue.. Dunno any other solution..

Comment: interesting thing - if I use same service in simple Table control and won't read oData, just bind it, i won't have this issue. Every output with slash is displayed correctly